# How to update multiple columns with different data?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to change data from different columns with different values. Should I use loop in nodejs and run the query for each data? or there is another query which can fulfill this requiremnt.
I have users table. Now i have to change the name of two users. In the given code i want to change the name of user with `id=1` to `name1` and the user and the user with `id=2` to `name2`. The following query generating error. What is the right way and syntax to do such a thing.

```sql
UPDATE
  UsersTable
SET
  `names` =('name1', 'name2')
WHERE
  id IN(1, 2)
```

Comment: 2 update commands in a transaction from node

Comment: so can i use nodejs for loop and run that query again & again. will it be an effecient way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE UsersTable
JOIN ( SELECT 'name1' names, 1 id 
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'name1', 2 ) data USING (id)
SET UsersTable.names = data.names;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.